# C# Vector The type must be a non-nullable?

Tags: c#

```
public Vector<lecture> GetAvlLectures()
{
    Vector<lecture> ret = new Vector<lecture>();
    return ret;
}
```

This is my code and I got this error(Vector: System.Numerics):

> The type 'lecture' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Vector'

I thought that class 'lecture' must be non-nullable which is not able to be a null but I could't find how can I make lecture as non-nullable. All I found is 'lecture!' which makes lecture nullable.

This is lecture class

```
public class lecture
{
    public enum status {
        WAITING_FOR_OPENING,
        WRITING,
        BEFORE,
        STUDIED,
        COMPLETED
    }
    public enum type
    {
        VIDEO,
        TEXT,
        DOCUMENT,
        PENDING
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public status state { get; set; }
    public type lecType { get; set; }
    public lecture(string name, string subject, status state, type lecType)
    {
        //Initialization...
    }
}
```

I wonder WHAT is cause of this error and solution too..

Comment: Is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1?view=netcore-3.1) the vector type you're trying to use? Because it's only intended to be used with numbers, not arbitrary data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint is in the error message:

> The type 'lecture' must be a **non-nullable value type** in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Vector'

A class (which `lecture` is) is not a [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types), it is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types).

If you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1?view=netcore-3.1) for the `System.Numerics.Vector` class, you would see that the generic `T` parameter is expected to be "*any primitive numeric type*". Which makes sense given the `Numerics` namespace.

Comment: Ah... It looks like I made such a stupid mistake to confuse Vector in numeric stuff and the other Vector in generic.. So ashamed.. Maybe I confused with C++. I think, in this case, I have to use List instead of Vector...

Comment: @alfksj "*Maybe I confused with C++*" - C# and C++ are very different and unrelated languages. You can't assume that what works in one language will work in the other language. "*I think, in this case, I have to use List instead of Vector*" - probably.

Answer (score 0):

As already indicated, non nullable types can be used with value types only like int, bool, datetime etc. lecture is a reference type, a class.

In particular, as lecture is a reference type, an expression of type lecture can already be null.

If a vector is x,y coordinate then you can use like:

```
 private static (int,int)?      
 GetCoordinates()

{
    return (1, 2);
}
```